# numebering from 1 when using range(len(a)) in python resulting assertion error

Tags: python, error-handling, spyder, gurobi

The headline says it all. I used it to name the output so I want it to start from 1. edit : I tried range(1, len(a)) but it won't work.

Below is my completed code that I run and I tried to numerated. I supposed it's because it will ruining the looping in the codes but I'm not sure. I just tried to start numbering the plant from 1 after the code run.

I don't know what's wrong

I'm a newbie in python so sorry if this is a silly question. Any help will be so much appreciated. thank you :")

```py
# Warehouse demand in thousands of units
demand = [15, 18, 14, 20]

# Plant capacity in thousands of units
capacity = [20, 22, 17, 19, 18]

# Range of plants and warehouses
plants = range(1, len(capacity))
warehouses = range(1, len(demand))
# Model
m = gp.Model("facility")

# Plant open decision variables: open[p] == 1 if plant p is open.
open = m.addVars(plants,
                 vtype=GRB.BINARY,
                 obj=fixedCosts,
                 name="open")

# Transportation decision variables: transport[w,p] captures the
transport = m.addVars(warehouses, plants, obj=transCosts, name="trans")

# The objective is to minimize the total fixed and variable costs
m.ModelSense = GRB.MINIMIZE

# Production constraints
m.addConstrs(
    (transport.sum('*', p) <= capacity[p]*open[p] for p in plants), "Capacity")

# Demand constraints
m.addConstrs(
    (transport.sum(w) == demand[w] for w in warehouses),
    "Demand")

m.write('facilityPY.lp')

for p in plants:
    open[p].Start = 1.0

# Now close the plant with the highest fixed cost
print('Initial guess:')
maxFixed = max(fixedCosts)
for p in plants:
    if fixedCosts[p] == maxFixed:
        open[p].Start = 0.0
        print('Closing plant %s' % p)
        break
print('')

m.Params.Method = 2

m.optimize()

# Print solution
print('\nTOTAL COSTS: %g' % m.ObjVal)
print('SOLUTION:')
for p in plants:
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? how are you using these ranges? range creates a sequence

Comment: `range(start,len(capacity))` where `start` can be any number `< len(capacity)`

Comment: `range(1, len(a)+1)` will probably do what you want; but it might be better to just use `range(len(a))` and add one at the point of display; or even not bother with `range` and use `enumerate` instead. As Sayse says... what you intend to do with it afterwards matters.

Comment: I'm using it in a code for numbering the variable, it will be reflect on the output and I want the output start by one

Comment: SOLVED. I chose to add one at the point of display. thank you Amanda!

Answer (score 0):

You can start from 1 using

```
range(1, len(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the "start index" in the range function. The value of the first parameter is 0 by default hence it starts from 0. For example, the following code starts at 1

```
mlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
mrange = range(1, len(mlist))

for i in mrange:
    print(mlist[i], end = ' ')
```

The output is

```
2 3 4 5 6
```